# How to use MongoDB in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mongodb

what I have to do when I will use MongoDB in eclipse? Are there any plugins or something else?
I want to save data from an Android app to a MongoDB over Servlets.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You would be running MongoDB on your development machine separate from Eclipse.

You only need Eclipse to develop your Android app and (I guess) those servlets.

From what I understand, the servlets will be talking to MongoDB. The only thing you need for that is the MongoDB Java driver (available on their website).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install eclipse plugin called "MonjaDB". Here is [link](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/monjadb)

It simplifies your access.